# Javascript error when logged in

Tags: bug, status-declined

When I am logged in on Mi Yodeya, many (all?) of the Javascript features do not work. I am unable to view my inbox or view more comments, the questions displayed on the front page do not update, autosuggestions for tags do not work, and I am unable to view my question as it will finally appear while typing it. I am getting the error

```
Expected ')'
full.js
Line: 166
Char: 320
```

This error started today and does not occur on other stack exchange sites. I am using Internet Explorer 8 (I know, I know... can't change it for now).

Any ideas why this could be?

**Edit:**
This problem is also occurring on Mi Yodeya-meta.

**Second Edit:**
I just realized that I'm wrong. This problem is showing up on all stack exchange sites. Could this possibly be migrated to meta stack overflow?

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't reproduce on IE 7 (*sigh*, thank you IT for modern browsers), *but* I also didn't get my username at the top.  I had to pop over to Firefox to get the logout URL to paste into IE.  (Which, by the way, logged me out everywhere, which was unexpected.)

Comment: Line 166, character 320, of http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js seems to be in the middle of a string (`".list-container"`). Odd that IE would expect a parenthesis. (I'm not using IE, but I set my user-agent string to `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)` to test in case different versions of the file are sent for different browsers.)

Comment: Hi Daniel! Did you try (a) clearing your cache, (b) making sure you're not blocking third-party scripts, and/or (c) ensuring you're not in IE7 compatibility mode?

Comment: @Aarthi, actually, the moment I went into compatibility mode, everything started working again. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: are you sure you turned compatibility *on* and not *off*? Post a screenshot...

Comment: @Shog9 http://postimg.org/image/xjf6tnwjp/

Comment: Daniel, since SE employees (have commented here so) obviously are aware of this, I don't see a real need to migrate it to MSO. If you want it migrated there (as, the more eyes on it, the more likely someone will know what's wrong), comment back here with `@msh210` and I'll be glad to do so.

Comment: @msh210, no that's fine. The issue is resolved now anyway.

Comment: @Shog9, oops you were right. I need to be out of compatibility mode. For some reason, every time I post, IE switches me back into compatibility mode and things stop working again.

Comment: It doesn't seem resolved to me: it's mere clarified as only applying in IE's compatibility mode. (Am I missing something?)

Comment: @msh210, the solution is turning off compatibility mode for stack exchange.

Comment: Yeah; compatibility mode is (IIRC) some sort of IE7 emulation - we don't support the use of IE7, and absolutely don't support compatibility mode.

Comment: "don't support" sounds like the high-tech equivalent of kashrus's "not recommended" :)

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized we don't support IE7.  I mean, it's not something I ever voluntarily use, but the dinosaurs in our IT department haven't moved past it yet, so if I'm at work and need to test something outside of Firefox, that's what I've reached for in the past.  I'll use Chrome for that from now on. :-)

Comment: Per @Shog9's comment I'm tagging this [meta-tag:status-declined]. (I'll also post an answer, just so it's not on the unanswered list.)

Comment: @msh210 Not [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @DoubleAA, either way, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in a comment on the question, this seems to be specific to Internet Explorer 7 (and IE8 in IE7-compatibility mode); and as Shog9 noted in another comment there, the site doesn't tailor itself to IE7's quirks.